# How to use Media Queries the right way for iPhone4/5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm developing an Application for iPhones. Now i have three Images which i want to be displayed the right way.

- Splash Screen
- Enter Screen
- Background Image

All of these are Images ()

I have to scale them because iPhones < iPhone5 have a height of 960px and iPhones ≥ iPhone5 have a height of 1136px. I have 2 images and my code looks like this ->

```
<div data-role="page" id="start">
   <a href="#start1" data-transition="fade">
      <div class="main_pic_splash"></div>
   </a>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*iPhone < 5*/
    @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
       .main_pic_splash {
         background:url(../img/splash/splash960.png);
         background-size: 320px 480px;
         display: block;
       }
}

/*iPhone 5*/
    @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
       .main_pic_splash {
            background:url(../img/splash/splash1136.jpg);
            background-size: 320px 568px;
            display: block;
       }
}
```

I cant get it work... i just get no image displayed. Hope u can help me, and tell me, where my mistake is :-/.

KR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background:url('../img/splash/splash1136.jpg');
```

You forgot the quotes

Comment: I still think this may be an answer for his question. His `@media` queries look fine to me, but not the url.

Comment: ...i realy forgot the quotes ._. so stupid! Thank you!